# store variable in json array php

Tags: php, sql, arrays, json

I'm storing the result of sql in a variable :

```
$Sql_Query = "select * from users where username = '$username' ";
$check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query));

$temp=$check['fierbase_id'];
```

then I want to pass the variable to Jason Array, am I doing it right?

```
$registrationIds = array( '$temp' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have a typo on `fierbase_id`, I think it should be `firebase_id`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it ,, $registrationIds = array($check[fierbase_id]);